# Class has no attribute error from returned data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

ive created a database which stores info that a user has added into a gui. The info is then returned by a simple function to be used in an another class which is where i recieve the error `'All_Contents_Page' object has no attribute 'c'` "All_Contents_Page" is the class name.

```
class AddEmployee:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("400x500")
        self.master.title("Add Employee")

        self.AddEmployee_ID = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.AddEmployee_FirstName = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.AddEmployee_Surname = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.AddEmployee_DOB = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.AddEmployee_Age = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.AddEmployee_Gender = tk.Entry(self.master)

        self.AddEmployee_ID.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.AddEmployee_FirstName.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.AddEmployee_Surname.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        self.AddEmployee_DOB.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        self.AddEmployee_Age.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
        self.AddEmployee_Gender.grid(row = 6, column = 1)


        self.AddEmployee_ID_Label = tk.Label(self.master, text = "ID").grid(row = 1, column = 2 )
        self.AddEmployee_FirstName_Label = tk.Label(self.master, text = "First Name").grid(row = 2, column = 2 )
        self.AddEmployee_Surname_Label = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Surname").grid(row = 3, column = 2 )
        self.AddEmployee_DOB_Label = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Date of Birth").grid(row = 4, column = 2 )
        self.AddEmployee_Age_Label = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Age").grid(row = 5, column = 2 )
        self.AddEmployee_Gender_Label = tk.Label(self.master, text = "Gender").grid(row = 5, column = 2 )

        self.AddEmployee_Add_Button = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Add", command = self.AddEmployee_CheckInfo_Confirm).grid(row = 3, column = 3)

    def AddEmployee_CheckInfo_Confirm(self):
        if self.AddEmployee_FirstName.get() and self.AddEmployee_ID.get() and self.AddEmployee_Age.get() and self.AddEmployee_DOB.get() and self.AddEmployee_Gender.get() and self.AddEmployee_Surname != "":
            if self.AddEmployee_FirstName.get() and self.AddEmployee_Surname.get():
                print("ayyyy lmao")
                self.AddEmployee_DatabaseRun()
                self.AddEmployee_AddUserData()
                self.AddEmployee_ReturnAllData()
            else:
                print("didnt work")
        else:
            print("Didnt work")

def AddEmployee_DatabaseRun():
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

        self.c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Employees (
                        ID Integer,
                        FirstName text,
                        Surname text,
                        DOB integer,
                        Age integer,
                        Gender text
                        )""") #Creation of Database

        self.conn.commit()

    def AddEmployee_ReturnAllData(self):
        self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM Employees")
        return self.c.fetchall()
        self.conn.commit() #Returned data


    def AddEmployee_AddUserData(self):
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (:ID, :FirstName, :Surname, :DOB, :Age, :Gender)",
                     {'ID: ': self.AddEmployee_ID.get(), 'First Name: ': self.AddEmployee_FirstName.get() , 'Surname: ': self.AddEmployee_Surname.get() ,
                     'DOB: ': self.AddEmployee_DOB.get() , 'Age: ': self.AddEmployee_Age.get() , 'Gender: ': self.AddEmployee_Gender.get()})

        self.conn.commit()
```

Here is the class where i am trying to run the function to retrieve the data:

```
class All_Contents_Page:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("1000x600")
        self.master.title("Company Database")

        self.All_Contents_Page_ListBox = tk.Listbox(self.master,width = 100, height = 20 ).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        self.All_Contents_Page_AddEmployeeButton = tk.Button(self.master, text = "Add Employee", command = self.gotoAddEmployee).grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        self.OtherClassMethod = 'AddEmployee_ReturnAllData'
        self.ReturnedData = getattr(AddEmployee, self.OtherClassMethod)

        for data in enumerate(self.ReturnedData(self)):
            self.All_Contents_Page_ListBox.insert(1, data)
```

I am confused as to why i get this error, is it the way i am trying to call the function from the class?

I decided against creating an instance of the class to get the function as i would just be ruining the GUI i am creating the instance in.

What would be the best was to solve this problem?

Comment: Please don't write code like this. Are all those functions methods of a class? If so why bother prefixing them with `AddEmployee_`? And if not, why do two of them take a `self` parameter? But nevertheless, you need to provide the rest of the code and the full traceback.

Comment: Could you provide the class' constructor as well?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the code has been updated

Comment: @VasilisG. The code has been updated

Comment: There is no `c` attribute in your constructor.

Comment: Giving all those `AddEmployee` instance attributes a name that starts with "AddEmployee" is pointless. It makes the code way too verbose, and the clutter actually makes it _harder_ to read.

Comment: @PM2Ring i'll change it.

Comment: Why doesn't the `AddEmployee_DatabaseRun` method have a `self` arg?

Comment: @VasilisG. Why would i need a c attribute in the constructor? its just a variable defined to connect to the databae.

Comment: But you need to define it *somewhere*. You don't (except for in a method you haven't called).

Answer (score 1):

The only place that defines a `c` attribute is `AddEmployee_DatabaseRun`. But not only do you never call that method, you never even create an instance of AddEmployee for it to live on in the first place. The `self` that you pass to `AddEmployee_ReturnAllData` is your current instance of `All_Contents_Page` - a completely different class which doesn't have a `c` attribute either.

It isn't clear why you expect `c` to exist, since it is only defined in that one method you don't call. Perhaps you could just use a connection defined locally in the method you do call? But really, you shouldn't write code like this at all.

Comment: Thank you. Ive added `self.c = self.conn.cursor()` to the init method. As for the code,  is it the style of code or the naming convention of the variables thats wrong?

Comment: The naming convention is certainly unidiomatic. But calling instance methods of a separate class without instantiating it, passing the instance of the current class as the `self` parameter, is violating several principles of both OOP and comprehensible code.

Comment: Creating an instance of the class would be the first thing i would do if it did not intervene with my GUI. As for `self` parameter in  `for data in enumerate(self.ReturnedData(self)):` ; the compiler asked for self as a parameter for the code to work. I count not find a way around it and didn't quite understand why i needed it but for testing purposes i added it in.

Comment: The point is that your class structure is broken. The database code should not be in the same class as the code that creates the GUI objects. Extract it into a separate class, which you can then instantiate in both your other classes; that db class can then define the connection in its init method.

Comment: I agree, the version before this i had the database in another class but that made it difficult to get the user info which is `self.AddEmployee_FirstName.get()` and for that reason i added it all in one class for convenience sake. I will re-write this code soon after fixing the bug. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

`getattr(AddEmployee, self.OtherClassMethod)(self)` is probably wrong in `class All_Contents_Page`, which is not a subclass of `AddEmployee`. Probably `AddEmployee.AddEmployee_ReturnAllData` is trying to access the cursor `self.c` on the `All_Contents_Page` instance, which did not receive a `c` member during its initialization.

It's not clear what your intent there is, so hard to suggest a fix. But that is the likely cause of the error you described.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Ive added `self.c = self.conn.cursor()` and `self.conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` to the init method but still receive the same error.

Comment: I think above all, what this code is missing is comments for each class and method, describing their intended purpose and behavior.